# A better way to explode twice in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, performance, explode

Given:

```
$val = "font-size:12px;color:#ff0000;font-family:Arial";
```

The following code will explode the string twice, to produce an array of arrays:

```
$val = explode(';',$val);
foreach($val as &$v)
    $v = explode(':',$v);

var_dump($val);
```

The output is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "font-size"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "12px"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "fill"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "#ff0000"
  }
  [2]=>
  &array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "font-family"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Arial"
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient / cleaner way to achieve the same result?

I'd prefer something with no lambda functions since PHP 5.2 doesn't support them. But this is a purely intellectual question anyway, so, that's just a preference.

Comment: It seems like [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) would probably figure into an answer.

Comment: @Jared: I was thinking the exact same thing. But I'd prefer no lambda functions

Comment: Then shouldn't you include that in your question?

Comment: What about your current approach makes it feel inefficient/unclean?

Comment: @Jared: Yes, I should have :-) I have edited my question.

Comment: @salathe Maybe it's because I've been doing so much JavaScript lately, I feel like I shouldn't have to call explode twice... or, that there would be a "cooler" way of doing this. But it's an intellectual question: my code works perfectly in production as-is.

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the place to ask for "cooler" ways of doing anything, nor to ask this style of question.

Comment: @salathe: Do you think there's a way I can improve my question? I'm looking for the most efficient, best code to produce the same result. (Or a better result could be considered as in hsz's answer... if it worked)

Comment: "efficient" in what way; for the developer reading it, for the machine executing it, for the hard drive storing it? "best code"… using what metrics? "better result"… can I return a string "blaaaah", is that better?  Apologies for lots of comments but you need to ask question that have answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$input  = "font-size:12px;color:#ff0000;font-family:Arial";

preg_match_all('/([^:]*?):([^;]*);?/', $input, $matches);

$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["font-size"]=>
  string(4) "12px"
  ["color"]=>
  string(7) "#ff0000"
  ["font-family"]=>
  string(5) "Arial"
}
```

Comment: I don't get the same output. I get `array(3) {
  ["font-size"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["12px;color"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["#ff0000;font-family"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend against references--you can run into some odd errors. But your approach is fine. Alternatively, you could do something with array_map:

```
$val = array_map(function($v) { return explode(':', $v); }, explode(';', $val)));
```

Comment: I'm very comfortable with references, so I'm not concerned there. My approach works fine, I just wanted something *cooler*. :-) Yours is nice although it requires PHP 5.3

Comment: "I'm very comfortable with references" -- that doesn't make them good to use :)

Comment: No. As with anything, they're a tool. Just because I have references in my toolbox doesn't mean they're right for every application. But in the way I'm using them, the references won't produce any odd errors, so I see no reason to avoid them in this case given that I understand them well and know why I'm using them here.